# Getting Error 500 after create a new method in a Controller and try to call the View for it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

So I am new to all this MVC, however this is what I have done so far..

I created a Model call Reservas with EntityF 
then Created a Controller call ReservasController..

within this Controller I created the following ActionResult Method:

```
    public ActionResult ReservasHoy()
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        var result = from p in db.Reservas
                     where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(p.fecha) == today
                     select new { p.Reservas_Tipo.Description, p.Cliente.Nombre, p.fecha };

        var r = result.ToList();
        return View(r);
    }
```

This return a List from the DB.

[image]

However when the View is load I receive a 500 Error

[image]

I know is a generic error and not sure how to debug this, again I spent already around two days trying to figure this out... but now I am just exhausted.

This is the configuration used to create the view..

[image]

and this is the View code..

```
    @model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Reserva>

       @{
            Layout = null;
        }



        <html>

    <body>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fecha)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cliente.Nombre)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reservas_Tipo.Description)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fecha)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cliente.Nombre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reservas_Tipo.Description)
        </td>

    </tr>
}

</table>
```

If someone can help with this I will really appreciate

Comment: Try `@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.fecha)`. Repeat this for Client.Nombre and Reservas_Tipo.Description

Comment: You also need to add a closing `</body>` tag and `</html>` tag to your view. It seems you are missing those as well

Comment: Hi Zac, thanks for the response. The html tags like body and </html> are there. I will try tomorrow your first suggestion and let you know the results, thanks

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, that did not worked

Comment: Comment out the entirety of your view, from the `<body>` tag downwards. Does it still 500?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var r = result.ToList();
r here is List<a> where a is anonymous class.
```

properties of `a` are

```
{Description,Nombre,fecha}
```

so, when view starts to generate it looks for `model.Cliente.Nombre` it doesn't get this value.
Replace your code with this.

```
public ActionResult ReservasHoy()
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        var result = (from p in db.Reservas
                     where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(p.fecha) == today
                     select p)
                     .ToList()
                     .Select(x=>new Project.Models.Reserva 
                     { 
                      Reservas_Tipo=x.Reservas_Tipo, 
                      Cliente=x.Cliente, 
                      fecha=x.fecha 
                     }).ToList();

        var r = result.ToList();
        return View(r);
    }
```

Now `r` is `List<Project.Models.Reserva>` , so the related fields will get mapped. Let me know if you issue.

Comment: Hi Raj, I tried your solution, which I got in return the following error: System.NotSupportedException: 'The entity or complex type 'UniModel.Reserva' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.' Now I am investigating on how to fix this.

Comment: @JuanCarlosArayaPortuguez Try now, I have fixed it.

Comment: Hi Raj, please see the issue below Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'Reserva' does not contain a definition for 'p' and no extension method 'p' accepting a first argument of type 'Reserva' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Project C:\Users\arayaju\source\repos\Project\Project\Controllers\ReservasController.cs 61 Active

Comment: My bad buddy just replace x.p with x

Comment: Hi Raj, it worked, the only thing I had to do after that is call a different instance of the DB Connection, for some reason was messing with my CRUD on the other views.. thanks a lot.